# Debian all tty hang on "Loading Please Wait" (Graphical Login works fine)

Tags: debian, tty

Graphical login works fine, but I need to be able to stop the xserver to install some packages, and then resume xserver. But all tty hang on"Loading pleas wait"

Edit: And just in general I like to be able to use the ttys, since it saves a lot of power to stop the graphical desktop and just use the cli. So I am NOT looking for another way to install the packages so please do not ask "What packages are you installing?" since that's completely irrelevant to the question.

Edit: (Changed question title).

Comment: Are you using systemd? What video driver are you using? There is generally no issue entering tty from X then killing X in Debian. Are you using: ctrl + alt + f1 to enter tty? You have to provide more information, which debian? etc.

Comment: You'll help answerers by telling the world, in the question, what virtual terminals you have configured `systemd-logind` to start via `logind.conf` and what systemd thinks a TTY login service is doing with (say) `systemctl status autovt@ttyv0`.